# How can a body be displaced from one point to another without accleration?

Tags: classical-mechanics

In definition of potential energy it is said that it is the amount of work done on object to displace it from infinity to that point without accleration .But how can body be displaced to that point without accleration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact definition of potential energy is as follows:-
**The change in potential energy of the system is defined as the negative of work done by the internal conservative forces of the system**

The definition you gave says that the work done by external forces in displacing object from one point to another without acceleration is known as change in potential energy.The acceleration can be zero if the internal conservative forces and external force balance each other.When the net force is zero the particle still has kinetic energy due to which it gets displaced.So a particle can be displaced from one point to another with constant speed.

Answer (score 1):

reason for zero acceleration is  ,we do not want to add aditional k.e in the total energy,our aim  was what amount of  work done  by conservative force  against or towards the particle /charge to bring it from a refrence level to certain point (magnitude) .

Answer (score 0):

I think it just means that the potential energy cannot account for the work done to increase the kinetic energy of your system: if it has a velocity $v$ in its initial position it should have also  $v$ in its final position if you were to compute correctly the difference in potential energy. Now in a thought experiment you could always start with $v=0$, apply some forces to accelerate your system and decelerate it back into a new state of equilibrium with $v=0$. You could still apply your definition to yield the correct (difference of) potential energy, based on the work of the conservative forces.

Answer (score 0):

The stumbling block seems to be that a body has to move from an initial position to a final position and so must at times during its journey have kinetic energy.

Conceptually it is perhaps easier to define **the change in the potential energy of a system associated with a conservative force as the negative of the work done by the conservative force in moving the body along any path connecting the initial and the final positions**.

As I see it the advantage of this definition is that it is irrelevant as to what else the body is doing as it moves from its initial to its final position because the conservative forces acting on the body do not depend on the speed / kinetic energy of the body. 
The body can be moving and even accelerating.

The definition of change in potential energy in terms of an external force has a caveat which is implied but usually not stated.
**The change in the potential energy of a system is the work done by an external force in moving the body along any path connecting the initial and the final positions** *provided that there is no net change in the speed / kinetic energy of the body.*

To illustrate this assume that the conservative force acting on the body is constant.
If the body moves at constant speed / with no change in kinetic energy during its journey then a constant external force, equal in magnitude and opposite in direction to the conservative force will result in the left-hand force against position graph where the area under the graph is the work done (grey - external force  and red - conservative force).

[image]

The right-hand graph illustrates what might happen if the body is at rest in its final and initial positions but moves in between.
The conservative force graph is unchanged.
At the initial position the body has to be made to move so the external force  has to be larger than the conservative force and an extra amount of work $x$ is done by the external force as compared with the conservative force.
However at the end of the journey the external force can be reduced so that the conservative force is now larger than the external force so that the body slow down and stops at its final position.
During this time the work done by the external force is less than that done by the conservative force by an amount $y \, (=x)$ and the net amount os work done by the external force is that required by the definition of change in potential energy.